# How to constantly update a canvas with a string?

Tags: java, swing, graphics, user-input

I'm attempting to make a simple game that displays the word that the user types as they type it.
However, I'm unsure how I could recall or update the **write()** method in order to show the string **currentWord** as the user types it, each time a new character is added or deleted.

I'm not sure if this is the right way to go about this or not:

```java
import java.awt.*;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JButton;

import java.util.*;

public class CopyOfGamePanel extends Canvas {

    public static String currentWord = "BEGIN";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] acceptable = {
            "pressed A",
            "pressed B",
            "pressed C",
            "pressed D",
            "pressed E",
            "pressed F",
            "pressed G",
            "pressed H",
            "pressed I",
            "pressed J",
            "pressed K",
            "pressed L",
            "pressed M",
            "pressed N",
            "pressed O",
            "pressed P",
            "pressed Q",
            "pressed R",
            "pressed S",
            "pressed T",
            "pressed U",
            "pressed V",
            "pressed W",
            "pressed X",
            "pressed Y",
            "pressed Z"
        };

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setFocusable(true);

        Canvas canvas = new CopyOfGamePanel();
        canvas.setSize(500, 700);
        canvas.setBackground(Color.white);
        frame.getContentPane().add(canvas);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);

        java.awt.KeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager().addKeyEventDispatcher(new java.awt.KeyEventDispatcher() {
            public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(java.awt.event.KeyEvent event) {
                String key = javax.swing.KeyStroke.getKeyStrokeForEvent(event).toString();
                if (key.equals("pressed BACK_SPACE"))
                    deleteLetter();
                if (Arrays.asList(acceptable).contains(key)) {
                    addLetter(key);
                    frame.pack();
                }
                //System.out.println(key);
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        backgroundGUI(g);
        write(g);
    }

    public void backgroundGUI(Graphics g) {

        g.drawLine(0, 300, 500, 300);

    }
    public void write(Graphics g) {

        g.drawString(currentWord, 50, 290);

    }


    public static void addLetter(String key) {
        char letter = key.charAt(8);

        currentWord = currentWord + letter;
        System.out.println("Current Word: " + currentWord);

    }
    public static void deleteLetter() {
        System.out.println("Delete a letter");
        if (currentWord.length() > 0) {
            currentWord = currentWord.substring(0, currentWord.length() - 1);
            System.out.println("Current Word: " + currentWord);
        } else {
            System.out.println("There are no more letters to delete");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Any reason why you're using `Canvas` for this?  `JPanel` would give you some more options

Comment: @MadProgrammer No specific reason, I've only really been exposed to Canvas in my java class, would a JPanel be more fit for this application?

Comment: Unless you're making use of the `BufferStrategy` API, there's not much benefit to using `Canvas` (now days)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for [`Canvas#repaint`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/Component.html#repaint()) to trigger a new paint cycle.

First, I'd isolate the keyboard input handling to the `CopyOfGamePanel` class itself, so it can do the update automatically.  If you need input to go through some other workflow (for some strange reasons), then `CopyOfGamePanel` will need to be notified (probably via some kind of observer/listener callback) with the information it needs and repaint itself.

```
import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.util.Arrays;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }

    public Main() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.add(new CopyOfGamePanel());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class CopyOfGamePanel extends Canvas {

        public static String currentWord = "BEGIN";
        private String[] acceptable = {"pressed A", "pressed B", "pressed C", "pressed D", "pressed E", "pressed F", "pressed G",
            "pressed H", "pressed I", "pressed J", "pressed K", "pressed L", "pressed M", "pressed N", "pressed O",
            "pressed P", "pressed Q", "pressed R", "pressed S", "pressed T", "pressed U", "pressed V", "pressed W",
            "pressed X", "pressed Y", "pressed Z"};

        public CopyOfGamePanel() {
            setBackground(Color.WHITE);
            java.awt.KeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager().addKeyEventDispatcher(new java.awt.KeyEventDispatcher() {
                public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(java.awt.event.KeyEvent event) {
                    String key = javax.swing.KeyStroke.getKeyStrokeForEvent(event).toString();
                    if (key.equals("pressed BACK_SPACE")) {
                        deleteLetter();
                    }
                    if (Arrays.asList(acceptable).contains(key)) {
                        addLetter(key);
                    }
                    return true;
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(500, 700);
        }

        public void paint(Graphics g) {
            backgroundGUI(g);
            write(g);
        }

        public void backgroundGUI(Graphics g) {
            g.drawLine(0, 300, 500, 300);
        }

        public void write(Graphics g) {
            g.drawString(currentWord, 50, 290);
        }

        public void addLetter(String key) {
            char letter = key.charAt(8);

            currentWord = currentWord + letter;
            System.out.println("Current Word: " + currentWord);
            repaint();
        }

        public void deleteLetter() {
            System.out.println("Delete a letter");
            if (currentWord.length() > 0) {
                currentWord = currentWord.substring(0, currentWord.length() - 1);
                System.out.println("Current Word: " + currentWord);
            } else {
                System.out.println("There are no more letters to delete");
            }
            repaint();
        }
    }

}
```

Questions pop up as to why:

- You need to use `Canvas` for this, this is quite a "low level" component, so unless you're actually making use of `BufferStrategy` it seems like a waste (and a source of possible issues)
- You're not using a `JTextField` (or if you're hell bent on AWT, `TextField`) to manage user input
- You're not using `KeyListener`, no offence, but using `KeyboardFocusManager` like this is a lot like trying to crack a peanut with C4, sure, it'll probably work, but it's also likely to create a mess.

I think you might want to take a look at:

- [Creating a GUI With Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html)
- [How to Use Text Fields](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textfield.html)
- [How to Write a Key Listener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html)
- [Painting in AWT and Swing](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/painting.html) and [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html)

If you're just starting out with this kind of stuff, it might even be better to look at JavaFX

Comment: As to the Canvas question, I'll look into the use of JPanels. However, for the text field, I want to limit input to letter characters and the backspace key, and the JTextField would not allow me to make this limitation to my understanding. Regarding the KeyListener, I decided to use the KeyoardFocusManager because it seemed like a better solution than defining every key and an action for it. Please keep in mind I'm new the whole GUI stuff and all of my judgements and thoughts might be completely wrong.

Comment: @JLoundy *"However, for the text field, I want to limit input to letter characters and the backspace key, and the JTextField would not allow me to make this limitation to my understanding."* - Is what a `DocumentFilter` is for - see [Text Component Features](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html)

Comment: @JLoundy *"I decided to use the KeyoardFocusManager because it seemed like a better solution than defining every key and an action for it"* is more of a "global" key event handler and is, as I said, probably over kill for your use case